# Cordova download in a loop

Tags: jquery, cordova, asynchronous

I want to do many downloads in a loop but I want to download the files one after another and not at the same time. But I don't know how to do this.

This is my download function:

```
function downloadFile(file_link, file_name, func, func_err) {
    console.log("dw start");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("dummy.html", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.toURL().replace("dummy.html", "");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();
            var furi = encodeURI(file_link);
            fileTransfer.download(furi, sPath + file_name, function (theFile) {
                func(theFile.toURI());
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("download failed");
                console.log(error);
                func_err();
            });
        });
    });
};

$.each(json, function (index, value) {
    var image_url = value.product_image;
    var fn = value.product_id + image_url.substring(image_url.lastIndexOf("."), image_url.length);

    downloadFile(image_url, fn, function (path) {
        console.log("download complete");
    });
}
```